# Line width in Konva js

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

just need to create line with image background. I found this opportunity in official documentation here (https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Line.html). For the start I just need to create line with tension, color fill and width, but the width property dont work(or I dont know how to do it).
My code and output:

```
let line2 = new Konva.Line({
  x: 100,
  y: 50,
  points: [75, 75, 100, 200, 300, 140],
  fill: "red",
  tension: 0.5,
  width: 50,
  strokeWidth: 1,
  stroke: 'green'
});
```

[image]

Comment: StrokeWidth will make a wider line. I think the width parameter is ignored for line since it gets its drawing information from the points array. Can you clarify your issue please - it is not clear exactly what you are seeking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, `Konva@4.0.12` doesn't support pattern for strokes. But it is possible to do with 2d native canvas API

So you have to:

1 - Draw [a custom shape](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Custom.html) and make a stroke manually

2 - Or you can use [Blend mode](https://konvajs.org/docs/styling/Blend_Mode.html) to mix a line and an image:

```
  const group = new Konva.Group();
  layer.add(group);

  // draw line
  const line = new Konva.Line({
   x: 100,
   y: 50,
   points: [75, 75, 100, 200, 300, 140],
   fill: "red",
   tension: 0.5,
   strokeWidth: 1,
   stroke: 'green'
  });
  group.add(line);

  // "fill" line with globalCompositeOperation: 'source-in' rectangle
  var lineClientRect = line.getClientRect();
  var fillRect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: lineClientRect.x,
    y: lineClientRect.y,
    width: lineClientRect.width,
    height: lineClientRect.height,
    fillPatternImage: img,
    globalCompositeOperation: 'source-in'
  });
  layer.add(fillRect);

  group.cache();
  layer.draw();
```

It may be a bit tricky, because `globalCompositeOperation` may effect all the shapes around your line. To fix that we can add the line and the "fill" rectangle into the group and cache it.

Demo: https://jsbin.com/zodojezuma/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Do you know solution without cache? Because of objects need to be draggble and I need to change size of this line, but when I cache group I cant do nothing with it

Comment: If you change the size of the line - you can just recache the group. If you have just 1-3 lines, you can use a layer without a cache instead of a group.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with Konva current version (4.0.12) to apply a pattern to the stroke of a line object. The snippet below uses a closed line with image fill pattern, but I don't think this is what you area after, but I created it to see what was possible and so will post it here in case useful in the future.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: width,
height: height
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();


// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);

var layer2 = new Konva.Layer();
var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({width:10, height:10, fill: 'magenta'})
var rect2 = new Konva.Rect({width:5, height:5, fill: 'cyan'})
var rect3 = new Konva.Rect({x: 5, y:5, width:5, height:5, fill: 'cyan'})

stage.add(layer2);
layer2.add(rect1);
layer2.add(rect2);
layer2.add(rect3);
stage.draw();
   
   
 // make an image out of layer2 
 // Note - be sure to include width & height when using toImage() otherwise uses size of stage and fillpatternrepeat will seem to fail.  
 var image = layer2.toImage({
    width: 10, height: 10,   
  callback(img) {
    // do stuff with img
      var blob = new Konva.Line({
        points: [23, 20, 23, 160, 70, 93, 150, 109, 290, 139, 270, 93],
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        fillPriority: 'pattern',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        closed: true,
        tension: 0.3
      });

 // add the shape to the layer
 layer.add(blob);
      
 stage.draw();

 var imageObj = new Image();
 imageObj.onload = function() {
   blob.fillPatternImage(imageObj);

   layer2.remove(); // no longer needed.
   
   blob.fillPatternImage(imageObj)
   layer.draw();

   stage.draw();
 };

 imageObj.src = img.src;

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/4.0.12/konva.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<img id='theImg' style='width:100px; height: 100px; border:"2px solid lime"; z-index: 10 '></img>
```